# Is the product of a diagonalizable matrix and a diagonal matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering if an matrix in the following form is diagonalizable, $$B=AD$$, where $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries strictly positive? It seems the claim is right but I cannot prove it.

Looking forward to your help. Thanks!

Comment: $$\pmatrix{-1&2\cr-1&2\cr}\pmatrix{2&0\cr0&1\cr}$$

Comment: Can you easily produce two independent eigenvectors then? Or a conjugation of it that produces a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @Nick, would you care to make a little wager on that? You know, $$\pmatrix{0&1\cr0&0\cr}$$ is also a rank-1 matrix.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could you provide a diagonalization of \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ -1 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}?

Comment: @Eoin Find the eigenvalues and then the eigenvectors. Alternatively, [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B-1%2C2%7D%2C%7B-1%2C2%7D%7D)

Comment: @angryavian Didn't know it did that! Thanks

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Yeah, you are right...it's a counterexample, but what if $A$ is nonsingular and all of its eigenvalues are positive?

Comment: $$\pmatrix{2&1\cr0&4\cr}\pmatrix{2&0\cr0&1\cr}$$

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: Yeah, you are right...I am naive...In fact the problem I encounter is the problem I post today...I suppose I can prove it via this lemma. Now it seems it's wrong...Thank you...